# Как разрешить прокрутку страницы, если у body overflow:hidden

Tags: прокрутка, hidden

Я хочу закрепить границы документа, чтобы при прокрутке не оттягивался край верхней или нижней границ страницы, как например на данной странице stackoverflow.

Для этого я выставил у body overflow:hidden и height:100%. Однако, когда я выставляю у div, в который заключен весь контент страницы, overflow:scroll, это свойство не перекрывает свойство body и страница не прокручивается вовсе.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как перекрыть свойство body, чтобы весь документ был закреплен, но его контент прокручивался и границы не оттягивались при прокрутке.
[image: Оттянутая граница]

```
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  body {
    padding-top: 50px;
  }
  .no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .scroll {
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  body {
    background-color: #2477ad;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;

  }
  .container {
    max-width: 1130px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .nav {
    padding-top: 6px;
    background-color: #23a359;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .nav-menu {
    width: 360px;
    margin-left: 230px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .nav-menu a {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 9px 20px 19px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .content {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
</style>
<body class="no-scroll">
<div class="container scroll">
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="">
        <h3>LOGO</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-menu">
      <a href="">Home</a>
      <a href="" class="active">About</a>
      <a href="">Work</a>
      <a href="">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="" alt="Some image" width="200px" height="200px;" />
      <p>Some text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="" alt="Some image" width="200px" height="200px;" />
      <p>Some text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="" alt="Some image" width="200px" height="200px;" />
      <p>Some text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="" alt="Some image" width="200px" height="200px;" />
      <p>Some text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="" alt="Some image" width="200px" height="200px;" />
      <p>Some text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="" alt="Some image" width="200px" height="200px;" />
      <p>Some text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="" alt="Some image" width="200px" height="200px;" />
      <p>Some text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="" alt="Some image" width="200px" height="200px;" />
      <p>Some text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="" alt="Some image" width="200px" height="200px;" />
      <p>Some text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="" alt="Some image" width="200px" height="200px;" />
      <p>Some text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="" alt="Some image" width="200px" height="200px;" />
      <p>Some text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="" alt="Some image" width="200px" height="200px;" />
      <p>Some text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="" alt="Some image" width="200px" height="200px;" />
      <p>Some text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Для полноты картины необходимо знать, зачем вам нужно, чтобы весь документ был закреплен, а его содержимое прокручивалось (грубо говоря, вы хотите 3, но не 3)

Comment: Рискну предположить, что вам необходима просто 100%-ая высота страницы, чтобы можно было устанавливать высоту дочерних элементов на 100%?

Comment: Извиняюсь за неясности, попробую объяснить еще раз. В основной вопрос добавил скрин. Как на нем видно, при прокручивании выше верхнего края страницы, край оттягивается дальше. 
Я хочу убрать этот момент, чтобы верхний и нижний края документа были пришиты, если так можно выразиться. Для этого у body я выставил overflow: hidden и height:100%, но при этом фиксируется вся видимая область, и прокручивание страницы перестает работать. Собственно поэтому мне и нужно перекрыть это свойство, чтоб основной контент прокручивался, а body был закреплен.

Comment: Подождите, а почему у вас шапка SO оттянута? Такого поведения быть не должно.

Comment: И почему нельзя просто использовать что-то на подобии `top: 0;`? Или я неправильно задачу понимаю?

Comment: Такое поведение (оттянутая шапка) происходит если на маке на трекпаде оттянуть экран дальше его границ, наподобие жеста на смартфонах, когда таким образом обновляется лента в твиттере к примеру или вк. Но на некоторых сайтах это запрещено путем присваивания overflow:hidden , как к примеру здесь: http://briandelaney.me/about. В данном случае html элементу присвоен класс no-scroll с соответствующими свойствами. Но я не могу понять каким образом он при этом добился прокрутки самой страницы, потому что у меня при таком заданном свойстве перестает прокручиваться вся страница, не только ее границы.

Comment: Ага. Теперь начинаю понимать. Что ж, сразу скажу, что системные настройки лучше не переписывать (если браузер ведет себя так, то пусть он так себя и ведет, не надо менять его поведение (если речь не идет, например, о добавлении желтой рамки к каждому элементу, что нарушает отображение страницы)). Но если это так принципиально, то попытаемся разобраться. Во-первых, добавьте к вопросу код, который вы используете сейчас и превью того (хотя бы примерное), как это работает у вас (ибо у меня нет возможнсти проверить это на маке). Дальше будем смотреть по коду.

Comment: Добавил код примерной страницы. В данном коде body дан класс no-scroll, который должен избавить от вышеописанной проблемы оттягивания верхней границы. Однако данный класс лишает возможности прокручивать страницу вообще. Чтобы этого не было, я попробовал контейнеру добавить класс scroll, в котором указал возможность прокручивания, но это не помогает, и страница по-прежнему не прокручивается вообще.

Comment: Да, я протестировал у себя, так и есть, свойство отменить невозможно штатными способами. Честно говоря, очень трудно тестировать поведение мака не на маке. Попробуйте, например, так: http://codepen.io/smellyshovel/pen/NAQxbY Если честно, даже не знаю, что из этого получится именно у вас.

Comment: @smellyshovel неа, у меня в вашем случае параметры никак не влияют на поведение, страница прокручивается как обычно с оттягиванием верхней границы

Comment: Просто проблема в том, что вы кодом, уровень влияния которого ограничивается браузером, пытаетесь переписать системное поведение. Даже не знаю, что вам и сказать в этом случае, ибо я даже не могу протестировать работу той страницы, которую вы в пример скидывали.

Comment: Честно вам скажу, оставьте это поведение в покое. Пользователи мака в наших широтах не так часто встречаются. Пользователи Safari - менее одного процента. Плюс вычтите то, что трекпад (насколько правильно я понимаю) есть только на макбуках. А теперь еще учтите то, что люди к этому уже привыкли, и поведение вашего сайта будет им казаться неразумным.

Comment: @smellyshovel Ок, спасибо большое за уделенное вопросу время!

Comment: Если честно, то не за что. Очень жаль, что не имею возможности вам помочь